# Fetching JSONArray inside JSONArray with unknown length

Tags: java, json

In my app I fetch a `JSONArray` from a server. The received data has this structure:

```
[
  {
    "MatchID": 51170,
    "Team1": {
      "TeamId": 1,
    },
    "Team2": {
      "TeamId": 1,
    },
    "Goals": [
      {
        "GoalID": 1,
      },
      {
        "GoalID": 2,
      },
      {
        "GoalID": 3,
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The problem I have is that the `JSONArray` 'goals' inside it has an unknown length.
I usually store and process all the data through getter and setters, like this:

```
public String getGoalid() {

return goalid;
}

public void setGoalid(String goalid) {

this.goalid = goalid;
}
```

But like this I just get the information of the last goal. I also tried to use the getter and setter as a string array, but like this I just stored the last value as well. What‘s the right way to store these unknown amout of strings correctly otherwise?

Edit:

Here‘s the code of how I process the received data:

```
List<GetData> GetData1 = new ArrayList<>();
 
public void Process(JSONArray array){
    for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {        
            GetData GetData2 = new GetData();
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = array.getJSONObject(i);
              
            JSONObject team1 = json.getJSONObject("Team1");
                JSONObject user = json.getJSONObject("Team2");
                GetData2.setTeam1(team1.getString(TEAM1));
                GetData2.setTeam2(user.getString(TEAM2));
               

            JSONArray jArrayGoals = json.getJSONArray("Goals");
                if(jArrayGoals == null || jArrayGoals.length() == 0){
                    
                }else {
                    for (int j = 0; j < jArrayGoals.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject json_data = jArrayGoals.getJSONObject(j);
                        GetData2.setGoalid(json_data.getString("GoalID"));                                                 
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            GetData1.add(GetData);
        }       
}
```

Comment: You can have a separate object `Goals` with attribute `id` and store `List<Goals>` for a `Match`

Comment: I usually store all the information into strings, since they don’t dublicate and add them to my custom adapter. And this result of all combined information I store into a List for every event. But what if the strings can dublicate? How do I store it into a List instead of a string?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer use `Gson` (https://github.com/google/gson)

**Gradle install**

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
}
```

for this case with classes like this

```
public class Team
{
  private int TeamId;

  public int getTeamId() { return this.TeamId; }

  public void setTeamId(int TeamId) { this.TeamId = TeamId; }
}


public class Goal
{
  private int GoalID;

  public int getGoalID() { return this.GoalID; }

  public void setGoalID(int GoalID) { this.GoalID = GoalID; }
}

public class RootObject
{
  private int MatchID;

  public int getMatchID() { return this.MatchID; }

  public void setMatchID(int MatchID) { this.MatchID = MatchID; }

  private Team Team1;

  public Team getTeam1() { return this.Team1; }

  public void setTeam1(Team1 Team1) { this.Team1 = Team1; }

  private Team Team2;

  public Team getTeam2() { return this.Team2; }

  public void setTeam2(Team2 Team2) { this.Team2 = Team2; }

  private ArrayList<Goal> Goals;

  public ArrayList<Goal> getGoals() { return this.Goals; }

  public void setGoals(ArrayList<Goal> Goals) { this.Goals = Goals; }
}
```

To get goals length will like this

```
RootObject rootObject = gson.fromJson(json, RootObject.class);
int goalLength = rootObject.getGoals().size()
```

Comment: I commented below the question, to explain my question a little bit more. Isn‘t there a way to just store an amount of strings instead of a single string like that and without using an extra library?

Comment: could you post other part of code to handle that json ? now still missing so will hard to answer

Comment: Sure, I added it

Comment: Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I still see many code missing so I cannot reproduce to help you

Comment: What is missing for you?

Comment: Thank you for telling me, I didn’t cut it correctly. I edited it. The GetData class only contains the getter and setter methods like I mentioned them above, nothing more

Comment: Do you have any suggestion about it?